# Полоса прокрутки элемента panel автоматически перескакивает в одно и тоже место?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, selenium-webdriver

На форме **Windows Forms** находится **panel** с полосой прокрутки. После возвращения в форму из другой программы полоса прокрутки элемента автоматически перескакивает в одно и тоже место.

**Что я делаю:**

1. Перемещаю полосу прокрутки на необходимое место в панели.
2. Перехожу в браузер. Делаю какие-то действия (любые, либо просто один клик).
3. Возвращаюсь в *Windows Forms*, и полоса прокрутки сразу автоматически перескакивает в середину панели.

[image: Коллаж действий по воспроизведению ошибки]

В коде используются `WebDriver.dll` и `WebDriver.Support.dll`. Среда разработки — *Visual Studio 2015*.

**Вопрос**: почему после возвращения на Windows Forms в panel из другой программы, panel перескакивает в одно и тоже положение,  а не остаётся на том же месте где и была до перехода на другую программу?

Comment: Боюсь, не видя кода тебе никто этого не обьяснит. Проблема явно гдето в коде формы.